# can't access Rails after change in name of user directory on OS X

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I suspect that this is a simple fix, but I also suspect that I could easily screw things up even more if I'm not careful. When IT installed drivers for new printers where I work, it required changing the name of the user directory on my MacBook Pro (running OS X El Capitan). This was a couple of weeks ago, and I haven't used Rails since then. When I tried to do a "rails runner" command today I received the following message:

```
<internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- rubygems.rb (LoadError)
from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `<compiled>'
```

I'm not positive, but I'm thinking this is directly related to the change in the name of the user directory. How do I fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a problem with your Rails project, the ruby installation is broken after your home directory rename. Specifically, it looks like Rubygems is failing because of that.

You could check the value of the `GEM_HOME` env var (running something like `echo $GEM_HOME`) in order to confirm that is the problem. Also, you could check the output of the command `gem env` which provides config information about your rubygems setup.

Finally, you can try to fix GEM_HOME env var (changing the path in your **.bashrc** or similar file). You may also want to consider to reinstall Ruby completely (in fact, this could be the easiest fix in your case).

Comment: Thanks--reinstalling Ruby did turn out to be the easiest way to go.